# Fullcalendar Scheduler Браузер зависает когда slotDuration 1 секунда

Tags: javascript

Так как я работаю с видео файлами, нужно чтобы точность `slotDuration` была 1 секунда, но при такой точности браузер зависает, так как должен рендерить очень много `views`.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и как можно решить? Я думаю при клике конкретного слота разбить на части в секундах конкретный слот, но как правильно его организовать?

Comment: помог ответ????

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#available_classes_calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
         left   : 'prev,next',
         center : 'title'
        },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    minTime: "06:30:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",
    slotDuration: "06:00:01"
});
```

Что касается отображения 06:30, 07:30 и так далее, по вертикальной оси, необходимо установить slotDuration: "06:30:01". Взгляни на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/y9mt92et/2/)

почему нам надо "+01" секунд
вы можете посмотреть в оригинальном [коде](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.3.1/fullcalendar.js) строка 5714 по 5719

```
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? // if irregular slot duration, or on the hour, then display the time
    '<span>' + // for matchCellWidths
        htmlEscape(slotDate.format(this.axisFormat)) +
    '</span>' :
    ''
```

Теперь $slotNormal определяется по строке 5701:

```
var slotNormal = this.slotDuration.asMinutes() % 15 === 0;
```

Вы можете найти ответ передйдя по ссылке [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444252/full-calendar-time-interval-should-be-1-hour-and-start-from-630).

Comment: спасибо приму к сведению

Comment: @L.Vadim такие сообщения со временем удаляются, пожалуйста перенесите из оригинала текст и код в Ваш ответ, а ссылку приведите в качестве первоисточника

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо за ответы, но проблему решил следующим образом 
при клике на конкретны слот беру его начальную дату (это будет minTime) а потом добавляю этому slotDuration и получаю maxTime, а потом рендерю scheduler для конкретного интервала но уже в секундах как и было нужно.